# How can an array of 1+ elements be at the same time not true and not false?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how can an element of 1+ elements return false if compared to a boolean?

```
> [1, 2] == true
< false
```

```
> [1, 2] == false
< false
```

I know that if the array contains only a 0 or a 1 a casting will be done and the comparison will return true if 0 is compared to false or if 1 is compared to true.

Comment: From spec: `If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).` -> it checks `<arr> == <bool>`, which does not fulfill any of the conditions in Abstract Equality Comparison, and returns `false`

Comment: Thanks, it did not look clear to me that no condition was met, especially since `[0] == false -> true` was still doing a casting, but I guess that is covered in `11.` in the link you provided